# Different with or Different from or others

Tags: grammar

I want to say a sentence with this meaning: "my book is not equal with your book". Which one is true? and suggest every other forms, can be used?

- My book is different with your book.
- My book is different from your book.
- My book is different of your book.

Comment: *Different than* and *different to* are additional formulations.

Comment: I did a little bit of research and "different than" is not widely accepted. http://dictionary.reference.com/help/faq/language/g02.html. Also, "different to" is primarily a UK expression, so it's important to make that distinction (in case they're looking for a specific region).

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/48656/what-the-difference-between-different-than-and-different-from?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

"My book is different from your book" is correct. "Different" can't "accompany" in these examples (referring to "with"), and it doesn't convey a part of a whole (referring to "of"). It serves as a distinction (which is "from").

Here are definitions of each to help you better understand:

[With](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/with?s=t)

[From](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/from?s=t)

[Of](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/of)

Answer (score 1):

As someone noted in a comment above, the "correct" usage depends on which side of the Atlantic you are on. Americans say "different from" while Brits say "different to". As an American I appreciate many UK-specific usages, but for some reason this one really bothers me. I think it's because "from" denotes distance while "to" denotes proximity. "Difference" to me implies distance so "from" fits much better. I'm sure a denizen of the UK would counter that they are using "difference" as a comparison and would then cite "as compared to" as being correct.  So there are strong arguments both ways.

Luckily any English speaker will completely understand both usages without hesitation.

Comment: In fact, Brits also use "different from". This is a really common question, and you can find a lot of sources that basically state "different from" = correct on both sides of the Atlantic; "different to" = a British usage, and "different than" = an American usage.

Comment: I must disagree. My late mother and two of my aunts (all native BrE speakers) were teachers and they would state categorically that "different from" was the only acceptable and grammatically correct usage in the UK. To them "different to" and "different than" were just bad English.

Answer (score 0):

The adjective "different" is usually followed by "from/than".  The use of "than" is more common in AE than in BE.  In BE, you can also use "to" but, I think, you don't use it in AE.

"My book is different from your book" is the only correct sentence out of the three sentences presented by the OP; the rest are grammatically incorrect.